# Word for bad legacy

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an individual word to describe a bad legacy in the English language. I'm looking for something that would fit sentences like:

> "Hitler's ~word~ still haunts modern Germany"
>
> "His ~word~ caused them to expatriate him"

While strictly maintaining the idea of "bad legacy"

Comment: For the second sentence, at least, you could use *infamy*. For the former, *spectre* is a common choice. though it needs a certain context to take on that meaning.

Comment: Was 'extirpate' meant rather than 'expatriate' in the second example?  From TheFreeDictionary online:  

1. a. To destroy totally; kill off: an effort to reintroduce wildlife that had been extirpated from the region.  
b. To render absent or nonexistent: "No society ... is devoid of ... religion, even those ... which have made deliberate attempts to extirpate it" (Roy A. Rappaport). See Synonyms at eliminate.  
2. to pull up by the roots.  
3. To remove by surgery.

Comment: What's wrong with *legacy*?

Comment: @JohnMack I don't imagine so. I imagine the trouble he caused, and the mess it made, caused them to *kick him out of the country*.

Comment: @Robusto It doesn't explicitly connote *bad*.

Comment: @DanBron: No, but through the miracle of Other Words "haunts" does.

Comment: "Bad blood" can be used in some contexts, but probably not the example.

Comment: @Robusto With enough context we can make any word indenotificulate anything. But that doesn't absolve us of our duty to choose the most appropriate and specific words we can.

Comment: And I believe *legacy* is all of that. YMMV.

Comment: *Most appropriate* is a superlative. There can be only one. Take this post as an exploration of the question of whether there is a better word than *legacy*, rather than whether *legacy* itself is a good word.

Comment: To @Robusto's question, exactly what DanBron mentioned.

Comment: The first word that came to mind was `ignominious`

Comment: @DanBron: *deport*, *expel*, or *banish* are more commonly used to mean *kick him out of the country*, but yes that does seem to be a valid (if uncommon) meaning of *expatriate* also.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As @Dan Bron mentioned in the comments I think the word *[infamy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/infamy)* works well 
in the first example.

> infamy
>
> The state of being well known for some bad quality or deed

*"Hitler's infamy still haunts modern Germany"*

As for the second example there are a number of words that could fit. You could use the plural of infamy with a concentration on definition 1.1.

> infamies
>
> evil or wicked acts

*"His infamies caused them to expatriate him"*

But you could also use other words like *[disrepute](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/disrepute)* etc. The comments section also brings up many alternatives.

Comment: Would blight be a valid possibility too?

Comment: @Arengorn In the right contexts, *blight* might work, but in your first example sentence, it's unlikely, and in your second, impossible.

Comment: December 7, 1941.

Answer (score 17):

This depends upon which word you wish to emphasize.

> Ignominious - (adjective) **deserving or causing** public disgrace or shame
>
> Ignominy - (noun) shameful or dishonorable quality or conduct or an instance of this.
>
> Infamous - (adjective) **well known** for some bad quality or deed
>
> Infamy - (noun) an infamous act or circumstance.

If you pay careful attention, these are very close in meaning with subtle yet powerful differences interpreted when I encounter them in use.

If you wish to emphasize "bad" or "shameful" then forms of `Ignominious` are the better choice, to my ear.

If you wish to emphasize "legacy" or "perception" then forms of `Infamous` ring clearer.

---

So, to use your example sentences:

> "Hitler's ignominy still haunts modern Germany"
>
> "His ignominy caused them to expatriate him"

Each of these places ***emphasis on the deserving of shame*** without necessarily placing concern on the expanse of his notoriety.

> "Hitler's infamy still haunts modern Germany"
>
> "His infamy caused them to expatriate him"

Each of these places **emphasis on the *public opinion* of perceived acts.**

One can be infamous for things not done, but one cannot be "ignominious" without being deserving of the label.  Ignominious is the stronger term here, because it directly asserts causation between acts and the label where infamy merely connotes a correlation between perceived acts and the label.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think there is a single word in English that captures the combined meaning of both words in the phrase "bad legacy".

'Legacy' itself is neutral, and is often used in negative context, such as "Pollution's legacy", so I think you could use simply 'legacy' in your example. No one would think you were commending him.

Comment: Agree!  What do all these answers have to do with legacy?  Here's my vote.

Answer (score 3):

Notoriety

no·to·ri·e·ty
ˌnōdəˈrīədē/
noun
the state of being famous or well known for some bad quality or deed.

Answer (score 1):

**Misdeeds** may fit in both sentences:

> ```
> "Hitler's misdeeds still haunts modern Germany."
> "His misdeeds caused them to expatriate him."
> ```

- *Misdeeds definition*: an evil or illegal action, a morally wrong or illegal act, which was done that should not have been, ranging from any sin or moral offense to various degrees of crim.

Answer (score 1):

[Disgrace](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disgrace) might fit here too.

**disgrace**:

1. the loss of respect, honor, or esteem; ignominy; shame
2. a person, act, or thing that causes shame, reproach, or dishonor or is dishonorable or shameful

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes our search for depth misses the answers that lie upon the surface. "Shadow" would work, I think.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Can you try to include reference or link (that can support your answer) and its essential parts? Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.